# Issues with data showing in control windows outputs

Tags: ms-access

I have an access control object that looks like below, each frame point to another table and can have 0-3 rows of number data that reflects in the window. This should be taking the sum of all the numbered data it points to and display the aggregate. However, some show 0 where they should not. For example, if I double click the 0 window here, it will pull up the data, and then once I close the window of the form it opens with the data - it updates and shows the correct number instead of a 0 in the window all of the sudden. What could happening here? - I am just trying to get all the data to always show accurately. Thank you

On click - the code to open the form looks like,

```
Private Sub AmountPayments_DblClick(Cancel As Integer)

    DoCmd.OpenForm "fpop_Payments", , , "IMEI='" & DeviceID & "'   OR IMEI = '" & Left(DeviceID, Len(DeviceID) - 1) & "'", , , DeviceID
```

[image: Access Control Object]

Comment: this might be an issue with no repaint/requerying the form. I forget which one is more appropriate in this scenario. I think the order of events might be causing issues for you here.

Comment: I just updated with some code @DougCoats - does that help reveal anything else? Thanks

Comment: no this doesnt help much. I nee dto see what happenes when the main form is opened.

Comment: I've gathered a few things - in `form properties` the record source is a master table that contains the 'Payments' column. It seems when there are multiple payments tied to a single record, something can get lost in not displaying correctly in the `Payments` control box. Is it possible to use the command control that points to 'Payments' and apply a filter to reflect most recent date? @DougCoats

Comment: Exactly what is "access control object" - a textbox? Exactly how are you calculating aggregate and displaying in textbox? Perhaps you should post to a forum where you can attach your db file for analysis.

Comment: Doing a little more digging on this I've realized that the control box (yes text box) points to the correct value in the table the Form points to. The reason why some show up 0 is because the table actually has the 0 value. The reason it pops up with a different value on double click is because the control box is also another form pop up on double click, that form pop up points to a different table with values. Hence a temporary updated after popping then closing that form, only to revert to 0 on original form load.

Comment: Ive narrowed down an aggregation issue in one of the 40 functions of VBA that calls like 10 different queries ping ponging data between tables left and right to end up at the final table... there is a disconnect between the final destination table and a previous table the control box points to on form pop. So the control box is both a display link (as a text box on main form)to another table and a double click function that pops a another form which points to a different table. Display shows one value, form pop shows another. Just a mess